# ImageMagick and rmagick OS X 10.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, rmagick

ImageMagick and rmagick gem is very tough to install. I tried using MacPort and then using https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer. I'm getting errors. Please help me to uninstall the uncompleted versions and to reinstall it again. I have already spent one day and I did not know it would take this long to do this small thing that too on mac. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I have to install rmagick 1.15.17 and rails is 2.3.5 and ruby ree.

Comment: Check out homebrew for the mac, its much better. http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: how do I uninstall the previous installation as it would interfere now with new installation.

Comment: brew install imagemagick now doesn't show anything. I removed macport using http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/

Comment: I have ImageMagick installed. I remember I installed it simply by downloading the source and compiling it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and then it's as simple as:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then add the line `gem 'rmagick'` to your gemfile and run

```
bundle install
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I noticed after upgrading from 10.6 to 10.7 I had to reinstall imagemagick through brew before it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this link https://github.com/maddox/magick-installer for installing imageMagick. After installing imageMagick try to install rmagick gem by

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Could not get this to work on 10.8.2, but homebrew above worked fine.